Create an Outlook email with signature and dynamic text in VBA
I have written this code to create an email with my signature, adding a dynamic text and attaching a file.
The text in the email is overwritten by the signature or vice versa.
How do I get the text to be included in the email? Where and how should the "TextForEmail" be implemented?
Sub SendEmail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim File As Variant
Dim FileName As String
Dim Tekst As String
Dim Signature As Object

FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Aftalesedler til fakturering.pdf"

TextForEmail = "Hi" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Enclosed you will find " & NumberOfPages " pages" & "<br>"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next

Signature = OutMail.body

With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Pages"
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & Signature & "</BODY></HTML>"
    .Attachments.Add FileName
    .Display
End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMa`il = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub


Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration

Sub SendEmail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim FileName As String
Dim TextForEmail As String
Dim Signature As String

FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Aftalesedler til fakturering.pdf"

Dim NumberOfPages As Long
NumberOfPages = 2
'TextForEmail = "Hi" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Enclosed you will find " & NumberOfPages " pages" & "<br>"
TextForEmail = "Hi" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Enclosed you will find " & NumberOfPages & " pages" & "<br>"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail

    .Display ' generate signature
    Signature = .htmlbody
    
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Pages"
    .htmlbody = "<HTML><BODY>" & TextForEmail & Signature & "</BODY></HTML>"
    .Attachments.Add FileName
    
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

fyi. Always delete On Error Resume Next when found just before creating mail. Fix errors, if any.
